# Chrome version 62.0.3202.94 3d issue rendering

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Can Anyone help me to solve a problem that I found on the last version of Chrome?
    I found a problem on Chrome new version regarding the DIV Background in 3D.
    In the Chrome versione 61.0.3163.100 the same page was rendered well.
    On Safari, Internet Explore, Edge and Firefox the page is rendered without any problem.
    I attached in this message just a little part of the original HTML page in order to show which is the problem.
    Thanks in advance

```
Andrea Angeli
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.corr-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cube {
  -moz-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cube {
  height: 550px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 275px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 275px;
}

.cube-face-top {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3300px;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
  background-image: url(https://www.trulytaly.com/ElementiGrafica/Corridoi/Nuovi/Soffitto.png);
  background-size: 100% 550px;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 550px;
}

.cube-face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.plaza-face-top {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://www.trulytaly.com/ElementiGrafica/Piazze/NuoviFilePiazza/CUT-FOTOGALLERIA2-B2-TOP.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  background-size: 100% 550px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

.plaza-face,
.r-plaza-face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.plaza-face,
.r-plaza-face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.rplaza-face-top {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(../ElementiGrafica/Piazze/NuoviFilePiazza/CUT-FOTOGALLERIA2-B2-TOP.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  background-size: 100% 550px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -550px;
}

.dropdown-flag {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content-flag {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

.dropdown-flag:hover .dropdown-content-flag {
  display: block;
}

.col-sx-dx-div-principale {
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1900px) {
  .div-principale {
    max-width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sx-dx-div-principale {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translateZ(20000px);
    z-index: 9999999;
    height: 900px;
    width: 5%;
  }
}


}
```

```html
<div class="div-principale" style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div style="padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;" class="virtual-container">
      <div class="corr-container">
        <div class="cube-container">
          <div id="cube" data-inverted="false" class="cube" data-p="front">
            <div class="cube-face ct cube-face-top">
              <div class="pt plaza-face plaza-face-top"></div>
              <div class="pt plaza-face rplaza-face-top" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I supposed that in the html example the image could be more explicit!  The Background image is not complete. On windows 10 the image is not shown and in windows 7 Chrome show a white area on the right of image that hide approximately half image. I suppose that the image is not rendered completely

Comment: I have seen that it is possible to show the images as they should deactivating an attribute on the Chrome Developer tool window. Open the developer tool window, select, in the HTML code the DIV with ID=cube and on styles tab deactivate the attribute -webkit-perspective: 600px; and perspective: 600px;. The images disappear then check one of them again and the images are displayed as they should. Any suggestion to solve this problem? Thanks in advance